# Wine version mismatch after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, wine

After upgrading to 18.04 I'm getting a version mismatch error when running wine:

```
wine client error:0: version mismatch 524/547.
```

Can't figure out what's interfering with what, especially since apt list gives me a bunch of packages:

```
fonts-wine/bionic,bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
libwine/bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable/bionic,bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
wine2.0/now 1:2.0-0ubuntu1~16.04~ricotz1 amd64 [installed,local]
wine2.0-amd64/now 1:2.0-0ubuntu1~16.04~ricotz1 amd64 [installed,local]
wine2.0-i386/now 1:2.0-0ubuntu1~16.04~ricotz1 i386 [installed,local]
wine32/bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 i386 [installed,automatic]
wine64/bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
winetricks/bionic,bionic,now 0.0+20180217-1 all [installed,automatic]
```

Running wine --version give me wine-2.0

Does anyone know which packages should/can be removed here so that wine is functional again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer: I just removed all of the non-bionic packages and life is good again.

Answer (score 2):

Wine currently has no Bionic repository. Best it has is Artful. Depending on how you installed Wine before you upgraded, I'd suggest looking at your sources.list in /etc/apt.

If you originally installed Wine by following the Wine guide, you should have a line similar to the following:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

However, this will not work in Bionic just yet, until the developers for Wine make a Bionic repository available. To work around this, edit the above line to:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main
```

If you don't have a line for Wine anywhere in your sources.list file, add it as above.

After an apt update, you should be able to install the proper winehq-stable and winehq-staging versions as reported on the homepage of Wine. When Bionic is available, you should be able to revert to the first line without having "artful main" added to the end.

Comment: Here are some of the bionic wine packages that were installed....I just removed the ones that didn't have bionic in their names: wine32/bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 i386 [installed,automatic]
wine64/bionic,now 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
winetricks/bionic,bionic,now 0.0+20180217-1 all [installed,automatic]