# Wine 3.x repository 404 error

Tags: wine, repository, add-apt-repository

I've been trying to install wine but the repository doesn't get added. I have added the release key it doesn't seem to recognize that either. Please help... >.<

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                    
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic InRelease                 
Ign:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
Err:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.40.69 443]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/forkotov02/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                         
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-unstable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [6,132 B]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,364 B]                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [12.8 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                
 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]                                                                                                                                                                                  
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,456 B]                                                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The repository does not support 18.04 yet.

Comment: This might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036158/wine-version-mismatch-after-upgrading-to-18-04

Comment: If you open dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu in a browser, you'll note they support a few releases, but not **bionic** (or 18.04), at least not yet; *hence the 404 error*

Answer (score 0):

I used the following blog this morning to fix all my wine programs being broken after the upgrade from 17.10.
https://linuxconfig.org/install-wine-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
They list the following which worked for me.

```
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ artful main'
```